# Highcharter hover showing incorrect point

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm having an issue where when I create a highcharter graph for Shiny, the hover functionality doesn't work properly. I have used highcharter a ton and have never had this issue, but for some reason on this dashboard, anytime I hover over a point it either doesn't register the hover, or it provides the tooltip for a different point. Screenshot example here. Anyone have this issue before? The red arrow shows where my mouse was when taking this screenshot. [image]

My code is below (note, there are two graphs in the fluidRow(), but removing one and making the graph take the whole row does not fix the issue).:

`############

## Code in UI

```
fluidRow(align = "center",splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%","50%"),
                     withLoader(highchartOutput(outputId = "lineChart1", height = 500, width = 700),type = "html",loader = "dnaspin"),
                     withLoader(highchartOutput(outputId = "lineChart2", height = 450, width = 700),type = "html",loader = "dnaspin")
                              )
                    )
```

`

#

## Code for the actual graph (in the Server)

```
output$lineChart1 <- renderHighchart({

impactData <- read.csv("IMPACT_dash.csv")
colnames(impactData) <- c("Week","notAtAll","notButWill","hasSomewhat",
                          "hasConsiderably","hasDevastating")

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = impactData, "line", color = "#404040", hcaes(x = Week, y = notAtAll), 
                name = "It has not and will probably never impact my life at all") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = impactData, "line", color = "#8f8f8f", hcaes(x = Week,  y = notButWill),
                name = "It has not but will probably impact my life in the future") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = impactData, color = "#91ad80", "line", hcaes(x = Week, y = hasSomewhat),
                name = "It has impacted my life somewhat") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = impactData, color = "#8fc96b", "line", hcaes(x = Week, y = hasConsiderably),
                name = "It has impacted my life considerably") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = impactData, color = "#83d64f", "line", hcaes(x = Week, y = hasDevastating),
                name = "It has had a devastating impact on my life") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      showInLegend = T,
      pointFormat = "{point.y}%"
    ), column = list(colorByPoint = T)
  ) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Percent"),
           #lables = list(format("{value}%"),
           max = 100) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Week"), categories = impactData$Week) %>%
  hc_title(text = "") %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "{point.y}%")
```

})

`

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: can you attach the simplest version of your code that creates a shiny app with this same error?

Comment: Absolutely. Just added. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also include some sample data? Something like ````dput(head(impactData, 20))````, then copy the output from the console and paste it into your question

Comment: Sure thing - just added the data set being used. Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error with your code and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. It was because in my dashboard I had set it to show the page as zoomed out at 80% when opened. This caused issues with the hovers in the graph. The code that caused the issue is below

[image]